# setNativeProps on Button Component

Tags: react-native, button, react-props

When I define a `button` in React Native as:

```
<Button ref="buttonRef" title="Button" onPress={this.buttonPressed}/>
```

And its `onPress` function as:

```
buttonPressed(){
  this.refs.buttonRef.setNativeProps({color:"#ffffff"});
}
```

I get the following error:

> this.refs.buttonRef.setNativeProps is not a function. (In
>   'this.refs.buttonRef.setNativeProps({
>             color: "#ffffff"
>           })', 'this.refs.buttonRef.setNativeProps' is undefined)

However, if I were to define any other type of component, e.g. `text input` as

```
<TextInput ref="userInputRef" value={"this is text"} />
```

With the function changing its props:

```
buttonPressed(){
  this.refs.textRef.setNativeProps({color:"#ffffff"});
}
```

Everything changes correctly.

Is there a reason that the `button` component is unable to have its native props set through `setNativeProps`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Button` component is a simple custom component created from `Touchable` components and it doesn't have a `ref` property. You can check the source code of `Button` component [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Button.js).

If you need to change properties of a component you should use state values for that.

**Sample**

```
buttonPressed = () => {
  this.setState({color:"#ffffff"});
}

//....

<Button ref="buttonRef" color={this.state.color} title="Button" onPress={this.buttonPressed}/>
```